# Link command line tf checkin to work item

Tags: tfs

I'd like to commit a file to TFS repository through the `tf` command-line tool and link the commit to a TFS work-item.  How do I do it?

I've gotten as far as committing my file, but without a link to the work-item.

My command adds a new file and commits the changes:

```
%> tf add foo.cpp
%> tf checkin foo.cpp -comment:"this is cool, but no work-item!"
```

Comment: You can use `git commit -m "my message #22003"` and it will associate the work item. I totally expected this to work with `tf vc checkin`.  But it doesn't. What a shame.

Comment: Another one to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578079/how-to-link-a-tfs-workitem-to-another-using-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not do this using `tf.exe` command line. If you need to use the `-noprompt` **parameter for automation** then you're likely out of luck.

Without `-noprompt` parameter, simply do this in *work-item* bar from UI. Select the workitem from your query and check the √, finally check in changes.

[image]

If this is a **checkin policy** in your company, you could also use the override parameter to bypass it as a workaround.

```
tf.exe checkin c:\workSpaceFilepath /comment:"some comment" /override:"Automated Build Process"
```

More details  please take a look at this similar question: [Can I check in to TFS from CLI with a work item association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017162/can-i-check-in-to-tfs-from-cli-with-a-work-item-association)

---

**Update**

```
tf checkin -associate
```

May do the trick as *KlingonJoe* says. However `- associate` is out of date

This may work with earlier version of TFS\VS such as VS2010 or team explorer everywhere. But it's **not work for TFS2015 and VS2013 and above at least.**

Moreover, to ignore the prompt, you could directly use `/noprompt`  in your tf check in command. More info you could check this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkin-command).

Comment: Another way is using powershell script and reflection on the TFS object mode. How to do this please refer the answer from *philip* in this link http://www.kinook.com/Forum/showthread.php?t=4502

Comment: Didn't even know that the prompt popped up, which would explain why the machine kind of hangs there after I press enter.  I need to figure out how to push the window through putty to my windows desktop.

Comment: Patrick - I'm running TF from Linux. The TF version that we've installed there is version 14.0.3

Comment: @KlingonJoe Thanks for the sharing. TFS doesn't have this version number(14.0.3), you can check [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have/). You must be using [**Microsoft Team Explorer Everywhere 2015**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727) It's make sense. seems `- associate` parameter is still working with Team Explorer Everywhere.

Comment: Based on the instructions on the website you linked, the TFS version is: 14.102.25423, that makes more sense (Update 3).

I'm not sure what version the TF tool on Linux is returning.  Let me inquire some more.

Answer (score 3):

This line command worked:

```
tf checkin -associate:55555 ...
```

It correctly associated the changes with work item 55555 and I was able to ignore the prompt.

Here is a link to the `-associate` option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475882(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Which version of TFS  and VS are you using ? Are you using team explorer everywhere which  the TFS  plug-in for Eclipse  not  team explorer in VS...  Your link is out of date. Either you are using tee or another reason is you are using VS2010. Which this command works on that version. Your answer maybe not so comprehensive.
Actually this command with `-associate` parameters is not work for TFS2015 and VS2013 above at least.  To ignore the prompt, you could directly use `/noprompt` More info you could check this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkin-command).

Comment: See the first comment @JohnHenckel -- you are correct -associate has been deprecated.  It appears that my Linux installation of the TF command is quite old.