# How to check-in the file in TFS which is checked out for edit with its check-in requirement

Tags: powershell, tfs

Below is the code which checks out a file from TFS and after it gets checked out, an updated file is copied at local path which I need to check-in to TFS. While checking in, I need to add the value in WorkItem by ID option present under Related Work Items heading and also the comments and other options.

```
 $TFSCheckoutExe="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"
    #File to be checked-out in TFS
    $TFSFilePath="$/Intell/Installscript/Utility Scripts/powershells/DI_UTC_Test.PS1"

    #This file needs to be checked-in in TFS after some changes are done.
    $Localfilepath="C:\Intell\Installscript\Utility Scripts\powershells\DI_UTC_Test.PS1"

    $demo="C:\demo\files to check in"

    #Checking out file
    &$TFSCheckoutExe checkout $TFSFilePath | Out-Null 

    #Copying the updated file to the mapped path of the file checked out.
    Copy-Item -path $demo -Destination "$Localfilepath" -Force

    #How to Checkin the copied file in TFS
    $ItemPath = "C:\Intell\Installscript\Utility Scripts\powershells\DI_UTC_Test.PS1"


    #Checkin the file by passing the required details which are require for checkin in any file.
    $null = & $TFSCheckoutExe checkin $Itempath /comment:"Added POC file" /notes:"Code reviewer=None ; Unit Testing=N/A ; Build Details=N/A" /Related Work Items:"Add Work Item by ID=86165"
```

The above code is giving error at last line for "/Related Work Items:"Add Work Item by ID=81165" which I want to add while checking in, which is nothing but the PBI number.

Below is the error which occurs while executing the script:

```
    TF.exe : TF10139: The following check-in policies have not been satisfied:
At C:\Demo\powershell scripts\demo1.ps1:17 char:9
+ $null = & $TFSCheckoutExe checkin $Itempath /comment:"Added POC file" /notes:"Co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (TF10139: The fo...been satisfied::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  You must associate this check-in with one or more work items.
```

Comment: Isn't Related Work Items expecting a list of Id's? Why are you passing the text string "Add Work Item by ID=" in there?

Comment: No, while checkin there are some required details which i need to fill before i check in anything into TFS. for eg - Code Reviewer name, Unit Testing, and so on. Just like that i want to input the PBI no. which we fill under Related Work Items:  heading by clicking on Add Work Item by ID option when we check in manually, but here i want to pass the value by script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for TFVC with **Team Explorer** in VS, "`tf.exe checkin`" does not support associating work items from the command line. There isn't the parameter:**/Related Work Items**.
See [Checkin command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/checkin-command#parameters) for details.

Also an issue tracked here : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/191

However you can try using **[Team Explorer Everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere)** with the below command to 
associate one or more work items with the changeset:

```
tf checkin ItemSpec -associate:WorkItemIds
```

See [Associate Work Items with Changesets (Team Explorer Everywhere)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475882(v=vs.100).aspx) for details.

Also this thread for your reference : [Link command line tf checkin to work item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660968/link-command-line-tf-checkin-to-work-item)

Comment: Now for CheckIn without WorkItemId, I am using /override parameter at least it is allowing me to checkin.